# Can't add customisations to B2C Sign-In Page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently trying to customise the Azure B2C Sign-In page and it seems quite restrictive. For starters the sign-in policies unlike some of the other policies does not give the option of adding a custom page to Page UI customization for “Local account sign-in page”.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5j6b.png)

When I try to customise the sign-in page through the classic portal I am unable to add text to the Password placeholder although I am able to change the username/email place holder text by changing the User ID Placeholder field.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5zNd.png)

I would also like to change the text "Can't access your account" to "Forgot your password".

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Sign up & Sign In" policy for this, this is a newer type of policy, which has more of the customizations features you are asking for.

It's on the backlog of the team to fix this I was told, but the focus was on the newer policies.

For the password placeholder we had the same problem, localization isn't available yet, and there is no way to change the password label at this moment.

Since the service is GA for a few days, we'll have to wait for the new features